# Сокеты hamachi и ip

Tags: сеть, ip, java, сервер, сокет

Я создал простой чат на java, запустил, потестил на своём компе, всё прекрасно работало, но оказалось что к серверу можно подключится только с ip 127.0.0.1, не могут подключится даже люди из локальной сети(hamachi) хотя всё порты открыты, и любой другой сервер (cs, minecraft) у меня работает нормально на техже портах и через hamachi и через внешний ip, и так с любой сетевой программой написанной мной на java. Как сделать так чтобы к серверу моего чата можно было подключится по моему ip их hamachi и в чём может быть проблема?

**Обновление**

Дело в том, что мне надо, чтобы к серверу можно было подключатся по ip их hamachi, а не только по 127.0.0.1. В программе всё в порядке. Я просто спрашиваю как можно повлиять на то, с какого ip можно подключится к серверу (раньше к этой же программе можно было подключится по моему внешнему ip, код я не менял и долго её вообще не трогал, а теперь её запускаю и к серверу не могут подключится ни по моему внешнему ip ни по hamachi, а только я через 127.0.0.1, и так случилось со всеми моими приложениями на java, которые раньше работали нормально), в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: биндиться не на локальный айпи, а на тот, который в hamachi?

Но вообще то ошибка в 17 строке в третьем файле слева.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что телепаты все в отпуске (лето как никак) и никто не знает, как там у Вас все написано. Может у Вас теперь злобный фаервол или версия java обновилась и теперь поменялось поведение (если там используется ssl - то вполне - корневые сертификаты могли обновиться).

А может человек с той стороны просто не хочет с Вами общаться через Ваш чат и придумывает:)

Comment: если на компьютерре из-за роутера закрыты порты, можно ли открыть их программой которой нужен доступ к этим портам?

Comment: Да, конечно можно. Главное, что бы роутер это умел. [Вот](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=188019) описание на делфи и С#. Думаю, можно и на java сделать.